# Connect CloudSQL instance using Private IP via Cloud VPN Tunneling

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-vpn

I have two projects 1 and 2 and two vpc networks vpc1 and vpc2 in the respective projects. I need to connect to sql instance in vpc2 (project2) from vm in vpc1 project1 using private IP. After trying diiferent methods and exploring options like vpc peering, cloud NAT (which wouldn't work for me) I found the cloud VPN solution. I am following this [google docs link](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip#vpn) to connect to cloudSQL instance using its private IP. I have setup VPN Tunneling and all the necessary steps that were mentioned in the steps 1 and 2 in the link itself, but not able to connect to the instance. I have tested the VPN connectivity as well. I am able to ping a vm2 in vpc2 (project2) from vm1 in vpc1 (project1).

I suspect the problem is in the final steps over here:
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/ecjzN.png)

No problem in step a and step b is also clear, but what exactly needs to be done in step c is not clear. Can you explain what exactly needs to be done over there.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation that you are referring to, you can follow the console instructions instead of the gcloud ones to get a little more information on that [step (the equivalent is step e)](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/configure-private-ip#vpn).

As per the intruction, you can find the the IP range by navigating the left sidebar to VPC Network > Routes, and I believe that the Next hop can be found in your VPC Network Peering instance's details page.